# Show n number of list elements at a time, jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to fit a large amount of data in the form of either a LI or TR into a small screen - status of employees on display via TV. The client is requesting the ability to show x number of rows at a time so that it iterates through the list.

For example, if there are 12 people being listed, only 4 would show at a time. 0 - 4, 4-8, 8-12, etc. If the number of people on the list is odd, the remaining few would need to be shown as well - so it could be 4, 4, 2.

Here is what I tried - it is showing 0-4 and then hiding everything, then showing 0-4 again.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Long List Test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var elements = $("#longList li");
            var index = 0;

            var showNextFour = function() {
                elements.hide();
                var location = parseInt(index) + parseInt(4);
                if (location < elements.length) {
                    elements.slice(index, 4).show();
                    index = index + 4;
                } else {
                    index = 0;
                    elements.slice(index, 4).show();
                }
                setTimeout(showNextFour, 500);
            }
            showNextFour();
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <ul id="longList">
        <li>One</li>
        <li>Two</li>
        <li>Three</li>
        <li>Four</li>
        <li>Five</li>
        <li>Six</li>
        <li>Seven</li>
        <li>Eight</li>
        <li>Nine</li>
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why are you using `parseInt` for variables that are already integers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using `.slice` incorrectly. Try:

```
elements.slide(index, index+4).show();
```

---

However, that still won't show the last element because `location < elements.length` at that point. Here's a rewrite that optimizes your code a bit more:

```
var showNextFour = function (index) {
    if (index >= elements.length) {
        index = 0;
    }
    elements.hide().slice(index, index+4).show();
    setTimeout(function(){ showNextFour(index+4) }, 500);
}
showNextFour(0);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/wE4S8/

Comment: Short and sweet. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There are JQueryUI libraries which do this.

For example, [Datatables](http://datatables.net/) does something very similar to what you want i.e. displays paginated data. It wouldn't be too much of a stretch to use a timer to rotate through the data instead of having the pagination prev and next buttons. In the timeout, you can change the DataTable iDisplayStart attribute and then call myTable.fnDraw to update the table.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    myTable = $('#longList').dataTable( {
    "aaData": [
        /* Data set */
        [ "One" ],
        [ "Two" ],
        [ "Three" ],
        [ "Four" ],
        [ "Five" ],
        [ "Six" ],
        [ "Seven" ],
        [ "Eight" ]
    ],
    "aoColumns": [
        { "sTitle": "Items" }
    ]
    } );   
 } );

</script>
<body>
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="display" id="longList">
    </table>
</body>
```

Comment: That should have been a comment.

Comment: Stop pouncing on answers while I'm editing them. :-P

Comment: I would never suggest adding a sizable plugin like DataTables for what can be done in a dozen lines of JavaScript.

Comment: Yes I agree that in the example given its using a sledgehammer to crack a nut but it depends on whether his example was simplified down or not

Comment: It's good to know that this plugin is out there, thanks for bringing it to my attention :)

Answer (score 0):

`.slice` takes in the starting index and the ending index.

```
var showNextFour = function() {
    elements.hide();
    var location = index + 4;
    if (location < elements.length) {
        elements.slice(index, index + 4).show();
        index = index + 4;
    } else {
        elements.slice(index, elements.length).show();
        index = 0;
    }
    setTimeout(showNextFour, 500);
}
```

[Link to fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/26nny/)

Answer (score 0):

jQuery's slice method takes an end that is its 0-based position within the set, not its position relative to start.

If you fix that, you have working code.

http://jsfiddle.net/UCSJL/1/

```
var elements = $("#longList li");
var index = 0;

var showNextFour = function() {
    elements.hide();

    var end = index + 4;

    if (end > elements.length) {
        end = elements.length;
    }

    if (index < elements.length) {
        elements.slice(index, end).show();
        index += 4;
    } else {
        index = 0;
        elements.slice(index, 4).show();
    }

    setTimeout(showNextFour, 500);
}
showNextFour();
```