# Jquery .resizable function - resize icon not displaying properly

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

New to coding and doing an interview challenge.

They've asked for a dashboard made from JQuery (which I've never used before).
Lots of help from W3schools and here in stack has me accomplished 100% of the functionality I need (even if the design could be improved: functionality first polish later!)

One of the bonus is to have some UI
/UX functionality, so I've made the divs dragable, and I added the snip below from https://jqueryui.com/resizable/ to make the divs resizable.

```
$(function()){
$( "resizable" ).resizable();
});
```

But when it runs, the little resize icon seems to do something different from the example on the page above.

Are there any ideas how I can fix it back into the resize icon, the way it is supposed to look?

```js
var $linkID, $linkURL

function changeTime(){
    let d= new Date(); //built in JS function
    let mm = ('0' + d.getMinutes()).slice(-2);
    let ss = ('0' + d.getSeconds()).slice(-2);
    document.getElementById("dateTime").innerHTML = `${d.getMonth()}/${d.getDay()}/${d.getYear()} ${d.getHours()}:${mm}:${ss}`;
}

setInterval(changeTime, 1000); //updates the time dynamically.

//Group1
//Click to Show functionality: group 1 
//clicks hide all divs, then uses a "title" attribute as a variable to toggle the associated box showing that title's information. 
//I am no marketer, so the text is some basic info I read on the websites.
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".clickToShow").click(function(){
        $(".clickToShowBlock").hide();
        let idTag = '#' + this.getAttribute("title");        
      $(idTag).toggle();
    });
  });

//Group 2
//Same as above, except using hover instead of click to show the images.

$(document).ready(function(){    
    $(".hoverToShow").hover(function(){let idTag = '#' + this.getAttribute("title");
        $(idTag).show();
      }, function(){let idTag = '#' + this.getAttribute("title");
        $(idTag).hide();      
      $(".hoverToShowBlock").hide();
    });
  });

  //Group3
  //follows group 1 method, but loads all links at the same time by toggling a button.
  
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#showLinksButton").click(function(){        
      $(".showLinks").toggle();
    });
  });

  $(function(){
    $("#showLinksButton").click(function () {
       $(this).text(function(i, text){
           return text === "Show Links" ? "Hide Links" : "Show Links";
       })
    });
 })
 //https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13652835/button-text-toggle-in-jquery

 //Group4
 //https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4511652/looping-through-list-items-with-jquery
// http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/wE4S8/
//from: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20105762/show-n-number-of-list-elements-at-a-time-jquery
$(document).ready(function (){
    var elements =$("#aviationLinks li");
    var index=0;
    var showTwo = function (index) {
        if (index >=elements.length){
            index = 0
        }
        elements.hide().slice(index, index+2).show();
        setTimeout(function(){
            showTwo(index +2)
        }, 5000);
        }
        showTwo(0);
    });

//Make key-value pairs on id and hyperlinks
const linkIDref = {
    delphiInfo:"https://delphitechcorp.com/",
    vrCityInfo:"https://vrcity.ca/",
    auroraInfo:"https://auroraaerial.aero",
    virbelaURL:"https://virbela.com",
    amazonURL:"https://amazon.com",
    moodleURL:"https://moodle.org",
    xPlaneURL:"https://x-plane.com",
    wordpressURL:"https://wordpress.org",
    gitHub:"https://github.com",
    googleMeet:"https://meet.google.com",
    slack:"https://slack.com",
    wrike:"https://wrike.com",
    airbus:"https://airbus.com",
    boeing:"https://boeing.com",
    lockheedMartin:"https://lockheedmartin.com",
    rtx:"https://rtx.com",
    geAviation:"https://geaviation.com",
    safran:"https://safran-group.com",
    leonardo:"https://leonardocompany.com",
    baseSystems:"https://baesystems.com"
}
//use key-values to populate the dynamic hyperlink functionality.
jQuery(".link").click(function(){
    $linkID = $(this).attr("id");
    window.location.href=linkIDref[$linkID];
})

$( function() {
    $( ".groups" ).draggable();
  } );
  
  $( function() {
    $( ".groups" ).resizable();
  } );
```

```css
body{
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:1em;
    background-color: skyblue;
}
h1{
    text-align:center;
}
div{
    border: black solid 2px;
    border-radius:10px;
}
#main{
    width:100%;
    height: fit-content;
    border:none;
}
#dashboard{
    margin:auto auto auto auto;
    display:grid;
    border:none;
    grid-template-columns: auto auto;
    column-gap: 1em;
    row-gap: 1em;
    width:100%;
    height:fit-content;    
}
#dateTime{
    margin:1em auto 1em auto;
    border: black solid 2px;
    width:fit-content;
    height:fit-content;
    padding:1em;
    font-size: larger;
    font-weight: bolder;
    background-color: snow;
}
.groups{
    position: relative;
    margin:auto auto auto auto;
    width:35em;
    min-width: 32.5em;
    background-color: snow;
    padding:0px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.groups h2{
    position:relative;
    top:-0.9em;
    text-align:center;
    background-color: blue;
    color:white;
    cursor:move;
}
ul{
    list-style-type: none;
    position:relative;
    top:-0.5em;
}
#group1{
    height:10em;
}
#group2{
    height:10em;
}
.clickToShowBlock{
    cursor:pointer;
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    top: 3.5em;
    left:12em;
    height:fit-content;
    width:20em;
    border:none;
}
.hoverToShowBlock{
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    top: 4em;
    left:12em;
    height:fit-content;
    width:20em;
    border:none;
}
.hoverToShowBlock img{
    max-height:6em;
    max-width:19em;
}
dd{
    padding: 0.5em 0em 0.5em 0em;
}
.showLinks{
    display:none;
}
#showLinksButton{
    position:absolute;
    right:0.5em;
    top:2em;
    font-size:2em;
}
li:hover{
    cursor:pointer;
}

dd:hover{
    cursor:pointer;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 1200px)
{    
    #dashboard{

        grid-template-columns: auto;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet2.css">
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Delphi Tech Corp Front-End Development Team Coding Test</title>
    <script src="script2.js" defer></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>TASK 2 Dashboard</h1>
    <div id="main">
      <div id = "dateTime"></div>
      <div id = "dashboard">
        <div id="group1" class = "groups">
          <h2 id="group1h2">Group 1 - Alan Zheng's Companys + Products</h2> 
          <ul>
            <li class="clickToShow" title = "vrCityInfo">VR City</li>
            <li class="clickToShow"  title = "delphiInfo">Delphi Tech Corp</li>
            <li class="clickToShow"  title = "auroraInfo">Aurora Aerial</li>
          </ul>
          <div id="vrCityInfo" class="clickToShowBlock link"> 
            VR City is a virtual aviation training company. Our virtual community provides people with the learning tools to learn how to fly. 
            <br>
            https://vrcity.ca/
          </div>
          <div id="delphiInfo" class="clickToShowBlock link"> 
            Delphi Technology Corp is integrating new technologies such as augmented reality and virtuality into the aerospace and aviation industries!
            <br>
            https://delphitechcorp.com/
          </div>  
          <div id="auroraInfo" class="clickToShowBlock link">
            Aurora Aerial offers custom drone manufacturing. We develop both drone hardware and software.
            <br>
            https://auroraaerial.aero
          </div>
          
        </div>
        <div id="group2" class = "groups">
          <h2 id="group2h2">Group 2 - Technology products used at Delphi</h2>
          <ul>
            <li class="hoverToShow link" title= "virbela" id= "virbelaURL">Virbela</li>
            <li class="hoverToShow link" title= "amazon" id= "amazonURL">Amazon</li>
            <li class="hoverToShow link" title= "moodle" id= "moodleURL">Moodle</li>
            <li class="hoverToShow link" title= "xPlane" id= "xPlaneURL">X-Plane</li>
            <li class="hoverToShow link" title= "wordpress" id= "wordpressURL">Wordpress</li>
          </ul>
          
          <div id="virbela" class="hoverToShowBlock">
            <img alt="Virbela" src="Logos/5fab9393da4ffe1e20d14cc6_virbela-logo-black-website.png"> 
          </div>
          <div id="amazon" class="hoverToShowBlock">
            <img alt="Amazon" src="Logos/NicePng_amazon-png_197561.png">  
          </div>  
          <div id="moodle" class="hoverToShowBlock">
            <img alt="Moodle" src="Logos/moodle_logo_small.svg">  
          </div>
          <div id="xPlane" class="hoverToShowBlock"> 
            <img alt="X-Plane" src="Logos/x-plane-logo.svg"> 
          </div>  
          <div id="wordpress" class="hoverToShowBlock"> 
            <img alt="Virbela" src="Logos/NicePng_wordpress-logo-png_395752.png"> 
          </div>

        </div>
        <div id="group3" class = "groups">
          <h2 id="group3h2">Group 3 - Websites used at Delphi</h2>
          <ul>
            <dt>GitHub</dt>
              <dd class="showLinks link" id="gitHub">https://github.com</dd>  
            <dt>Google Meet</dt>
              <dd class="showLinks link" id="googleMeet">https://meet.google.com</dd>
            <dt>Slack</dt>
              <dd class="showLinks link" id="slack">https://slack.com</dd>
            <dt>Wrike</dt>
              <dd class="showLinks link" id="wrike">https://wrike.com</dd>    
          </ul>
          <button id="showLinksButton">Show Links</button>
        </div>
        <div id="group4" class = "groups">
          <h2 id="group4h2">Group 4 - Aerospace Companies</h2>

          <ul id="aviationLinks">
            <li class = "cycle link" id="airbus">airbus.com</li> 
            <li class = "cycle link" id="boeing">boeing.com</li>
            <li class = "cycle link" id="lockheedMartin">lockheedmartin.com</li>
            <li class = "cycle link" id="rtx">rtx.com</li>
            <li class = "cycle link" id="geAviation">geaviation.com</li>
            <li class = "cycle link" id="safran">safran-group.com</li>
            <li class = "cycle link" id="leonardo">leonardocompany.com</li>
            <li class = "cycle link" id="baseSystems">baesystems.com</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply did not use the jQuery-ui CSS file...

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
```

And you have a way too "wide" rule on `div`. So specific to the rezise handles, it needed an exception using the [`:not()` selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not).

```
div:not(.ui-resizable-handle){
```

```js
var $linkID, $linkURL

function changeTime(){
    let d= new Date(); //built in JS function
    let mm = ('0' + d.getMinutes()).slice(-2);
    let ss = ('0' + d.getSeconds()).slice(-2);
    document.getElementById("dateTime").innerHTML = `${d.getMonth()}/${d.getDay()}/${d.getYear()} ${d.getHours()}:${mm}:${ss}`;
}

setInterval(changeTime, 1000); //updates the time dynamically.

//Group1
//Click to Show functionality: group 1 
//clicks hide all divs, then uses a "title" attribute as a variable to toggle the associated box showing that title's information. 
//I am no marketer, so the text is some basic info I read on the websites.
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".clickToShow").click(function(){
        $(".clickToShowBlock").hide();
        let idTag = '#' + this.getAttribute("title");        
      $(idTag).toggle();
    });
  });

//Group 2
//Same as above, except using hover instead of click to show the images.

$(document).ready(function(){    
    $(".hoverToShow").hover(function(){let idTag = '#' + this.getAttribute("title");
        $(idTag).show();
      }, function(){let idTag = '#' + this.getAttribute("title");
        $(idTag).hide();      
      $(".hoverToShowBlock").hide();
    });
  });

  //Group3
  //follows group 1 method, but loads all links at the same time by toggling a button.
  
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#showLinksButton").click(function(){        
      $(".showLinks").toggle();
    });
  });

  $(function(){
    $("#showLinksButton").click(function () {
       $(this).text(function(i, text){
           return text === "Show Links" ? "Hide Links" : "Show Links";
       })
    });
 })
 //https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13652835/button-text-toggle-in-jquery

 //Group4
 //https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4511652/looping-through-list-items-with-jquery
// http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/wE4S8/
//from: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20105762/show-n-number-of-list-elements-at-a-time-jquery
$(document).ready(function (){
    var elements =$("#aviationLinks li");
    var index=0;
    var showTwo = function (index) {
        if (index >=elements.length){
            index = 0
        }
        elements.hide().slice(index, index+2).show();
        setTimeout(function(){
            showTwo(index +2)
        }, 5000);
        }
        showTwo(0);
    });

//Make key-value pairs on id and hyperlinks
const linkIDref = {
    delphiInfo:"https://delphitechcorp.com/",
    vrCityInfo:"https://vrcity.ca/",
    auroraInfo:"https://auroraaerial.aero",
    virbelaURL:"https://virbela.com",
    amazonURL:"https://amazon.com",
    moodleURL:"https://moodle.org",
    xPlaneURL:"https://x-plane.com",
    wordpressURL:"https://wordpress.org",
    gitHub:"https://github.com",
    googleMeet:"https://meet.google.com",
    slack:"https://slack.com",
    wrike:"https://wrike.com",
    airbus:"https://airbus.com",
    boeing:"https://boeing.com",
    lockheedMartin:"https://lockheedmartin.com",
    rtx:"https://rtx.com",
    geAviation:"https://geaviation.com",
    safran:"https://safran-group.com",
    leonardo:"https://leonardocompany.com",
    baseSystems:"https://baesystems.com"
}
//use key-values to populate the dynamic hyperlink functionality.
jQuery(".link").click(function(){
    $linkID = $(this).attr("id");
    window.location.href=linkIDref[$linkID];
})

$( function() {
    $( ".groups" ).draggable();
  } );
  
  $( function() {
    $( ".groups" ).resizable();
  } );
```

```css
body{
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:1em;
    background-color: skyblue;
}
h1{
    text-align:center;
}
div:not(.ui-resizable-handle){  /* Added an exception to your generic rule */
    border: black solid 2px;
    border-radius:10px;
}
#main{
    width:100%;
    height: fit-content;
    border:none;
}
#dashboard{
    margin:auto auto auto auto;
    display:grid;
    border:none;
    grid-template-columns: auto auto;
    column-gap: 1em;
    row-gap: 1em;
    width:100%;
    height:fit-content;    
}
#dateTime{
    margin:1em auto 1em auto;
    border: black solid 2px;
    width:fit-content;
    height:fit-content;
    padding:1em;
    font-size: larger;
    font-weight: bolder;
    background-color: snow;
}
.groups{
    position: relative;
    margin:auto auto auto auto;
    width:35em;
    min-width: 32.5em;
    background-color: snow;
    padding:0px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.groups h2{
    position:relative;
    top:-0.9em;
    text-align:center;
    background-color: blue;
    color:white;
    cursor:move;
}
ul{
    list-style-type: none;
    position:relative;
    top:-0.5em;
}
#group1{
    height:10em;
}
#group2{
    height:10em;
}
.clickToShowBlock{
    cursor:pointer;
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    top: 3.5em;
    left:12em;
    height:fit-content;
    width:20em;
    border:none;
}
.hoverToShowBlock{
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    top: 4em;
    left:12em;
    height:fit-content;
    width:20em;
    border:none;
}
.hoverToShowBlock img{
    max-height:6em;
    max-width:19em;
}
dd{
    padding: 0.5em 0em 0.5em 0em;
}
.showLinks{
    display:none;
}
#showLinksButton{
    position:absolute;
    right:0.5em;
    top:2em;
    font-size:2em;
}
li:hover{
    cursor:pointer;
}

dd:hover{
    cursor:pointer;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 1200px)
{    
    #dashboard{

        grid-template-columns: auto;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css"><!-- Added the jQuery-ui CSS file -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet2.css">
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Delphi Tech Corp Front-End Development Team Coding Test</title>
    <script src="script2.js" defer></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>TASK 2 Dashboard</h1>
    <div id="main">
      <div id = "dateTime"></div>
      <div id = "dashboard">
        <div id="group1" class = "groups">
          <h2 id="group1h2">Group 1 - Alan Zheng's Companys + Products</h2> 
          <ul>
            <li class="clickToShow" title = "vrCityInfo">VR City</li>
            <li class="clickToShow"  title = "delphiInfo">Delphi Tech Corp</li>
            <li class="clickToShow"  title = "auroraInfo">Aurora Aerial</li>
          </ul>
          <div id="vrCityInfo" class="clickToShowBlock link"> 
            VR City is a virtual aviation training company. Our virtual community provides people with the learning tools to learn how to fly. 
            <br>
            https://vrcity.ca/
          </div>
          <div id="delphiInfo" class="clickToShowBlock link"> 
            Delphi Technology Corp is integrating new technologies such as augmented reality and virtuality into the aerospace and aviation industries!
            <br>
            https://delphitechcorp.com/
          </div>  
          <div id="auroraInfo" class="clickToShowBlock link">
            Aurora Aerial offers custom drone manufacturing. We develop both drone hardware and software.
            <br>
            https://auroraaerial.aero
          </div>
          
        </div>
        <div id="group2" class = "groups">
          <h2 id="group2h2">Group 2 - Technology products used at Delphi</h2>
          <ul>
            <li class="hoverToShow link" title= "virbela" id= "virbelaURL">Virbela</li>
            <li class="hoverToShow link" title= "amazon" id= "amazonURL">Amazon</li>
            <li class="hoverToShow link" title= "moodle" id= "moodleURL">Moodle</li>
            <li class="hoverToShow link" title= "xPlane" id= "xPlaneURL">X-Plane</li>
            <li class="hoverToShow link" title= "wordpress" id= "wordpressURL">Wordpress</li>
          </ul>
          
          <div id="virbela" class="hoverToShowBlock">
            <img alt="Virbela" src="Logos/5fab9393da4ffe1e20d14cc6_virbela-logo-black-website.png"> 
          </div>
          <div id="amazon" class="hoverToShowBlock">
            <img alt="Amazon" src="Logos/NicePng_amazon-png_197561.png">  
          </div>  
          <div id="moodle" class="hoverToShowBlock">
            <img alt="Moodle" src="Logos/moodle_logo_small.svg">  
          </div>
          <div id="xPlane" class="hoverToShowBlock"> 
            <img alt="X-Plane" src="Logos/x-plane-logo.svg"> 
          </div>  
          <div id="wordpress" class="hoverToShowBlock"> 
            <img alt="Virbela" src="Logos/NicePng_wordpress-logo-png_395752.png"> 
          </div>

        </div>
        <div id="group3" class = "groups">
          <h2 id="group3h2">Group 3 - Websites used at Delphi</h2>
          <ul>
            <dt>GitHub</dt>
              <dd class="showLinks link" id="gitHub">https://github.com</dd>  
            <dt>Google Meet</dt>
              <dd class="showLinks link" id="googleMeet">https://meet.google.com</dd>
            <dt>Slack</dt>
              <dd class="showLinks link" id="slack">https://slack.com</dd>
            <dt>Wrike</dt>
              <dd class="showLinks link" id="wrike">https://wrike.com</dd>    
          </ul>
          <button id="showLinksButton">Show Links</button>
        </div>
        <div id="group4" class = "groups">
          <h2 id="group4h2">Group 4 - Aerospace Companies</h2>

          <ul id="aviationLinks">
            <li class = "cycle link" id="airbus">airbus.com</li> 
            <li class = "cycle link" id="boeing">boeing.com</li>
            <li class = "cycle link" id="lockheedMartin">lockheedmartin.com</li>
            <li class = "cycle link" id="rtx">rtx.com</li>
            <li class = "cycle link" id="geAviation">geaviation.com</li>
            <li class = "cycle link" id="safran">safran-group.com</li>
            <li class = "cycle link" id="leonardo">leonardocompany.com</li>
            <li class = "cycle link" id="baseSystems">baesystems.com</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you!
I did not even know I needed it! Last night was a lot of "how do I ... with Jquery" googling! I missed the requirement for a separate css file!